# Check length of a string is equal to the number appended at its last

Tags: java, brute-force

what can be a possible way to check length of a string is equal to the number appended at its last. I am attaching a code I wrote any help is appreciated.

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str = "abcd10";
    String[] part = str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
    String strPart1 = part[0];
    int n = str.length();

        // Traverse string from end and find the number
        // stored at the end.
        // x is used to store power of 10.
        int num = 0, x = 1, i = n-1;

        for (i=n-1; i>=0; i--) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if ('0' <= c &&  c  <= '9') {
                num = (c - '0')*x + num;
                x = x * 10;
                System.out.println("true");
            } else break;
        }    
   }
}
```

Comment: Use a `Pattern` for matching integers. Get a `Matcher` for it. The `start()` returns you the beginning index. `group()` method returns you the number.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) with the second `String` from your `part` array (`10` in your post). Then check if the length of the first element matches. Something like,

```
String[] part = str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
int len = Integer.parseInt(part[1]);
if (len == part[0].length()) {
    System.out.printf("Yes. The length of %s is %d.%n", part[0], len);
} else {
    System.out.printf("No. The length of %s(%d) is not %d.%n", 
            part[0], part[0].length(), len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already split the string into two parts, which are both stored in `part`. So `part[0]` should be `"abcd"` while `part[1]` should be `"10"`. So all you need to do is convert `part[1]` to an integer and compare that value to the length of `part[0]` like so,

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(part[1]);
if(num == part[0].length()){
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter and increment it within your `if`

```
int digitCount = 0;

if ('0' <= c &&  c  <= '9') { 
    digitCount++;
    ...
}
```

and finally(after evaluating n, i.e post `for` loop) check

```
if(num == (n-digitCount)) {
   System.out.println("Yes the length is same as the number at last.");
} else ..not
```